# Add a new field to Javascript Fetch response object

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, field, response, fetch

I am doing a map with markers. I got the geo coordinates data from fetching a google api url. But for the markers, I need additional information coming from elsewhere. Is it possible to attach this additional information to the response I got from fetching the url? Thanks a lot!

The code:

```
var location = "Seattle";
var username = "Test user";
var time = "8th March 2017";

function toMap(location, username, time) {
    if (location.length > 0) { 
        var googleURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+location+"&key=Your_API_Key";
        fetch(googleURL)
            .then(function(response) {

     // Can I add "location", "username", and "time" to the response result here 
     //  before returning it?????

                return response.json();
             })
            .then(addMarker);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `response.json()` returns a `Promise` of `Object`, you can do it in another `then()` callback.

```
var location = "Seattle";
var username = "Test user";
var time = "8th March 2017";

function toMap(location, username, time) {
    if (location.length > 0) { 
        var googleURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+location+"&key=Your_API_Key";
        fetch(googleURL)
            .then(function(response) {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function(json) {
                json.location = location;
                json.username = username;
                json.time = time;
                return json;
            })
            .then(addMarker);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> [Body.json()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json) The `json()` method of the `Body` mixin takes a
>   `Response` stream and reads it to completion. It returns a promise
>   that resolves with an object literal containing the JSON data.

You can chain `.then()` to `.json()`, within `.then()` handler call set properties, values at `javascript` plain object, `return` object as parameter

```
  fetch(googleURL)
  .then(function(response) {

    // Can I add "location", "username", and "time" to the response result here 
    //  before returning it?????

    return response.json().then(function(json) {
      json.location = "abc";
      json.username = "def";
      json.time = 123;
      return json;
    });
  })
  .then(addMarker);
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can add any field you want to the response object

Let's say

```
fetch(googleURL)
            .then(function(response) {
               //set these values to anything
               response.location = "";
               response.username = "";
               response.time = "";

               return response.json();
             })
            .then(addMarker);
```

Comment: Note, `response` is not `response.json()`